# String compression and comparison

Tags: c++, string, bitset

Recently, I started writing a program to compare DNA sequence.  As the alphabet only consists of four letters (ATCG), compressing each character to 2 bits seemed like it would offer faster comparisons (are two characters the same or different). However, when I ran a test char comparisons were much faster than bit comparisons (by ~30%).  Compression was carried out in both programs as a control.  What am I missing here?  Is there a more efficient way to compare bits?
p.s. I also tried vector, but it was a bit slower than bitset.

```
// File: bittest.cc
// Test use of bitset container

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void compress(string&, bitset<74>&);
void compare(bitset<74>&, bitset<74>&);

int main()
{
   // Start timer
   std::clock_t start;
   double difference;
   start = std::clock();

   for(int i=0; i<10000000; ++i){
      string frag1="ATCGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGA";
      string frag2="AACGAACGAACGAACGAACGAACGAACGAACGAACGA";
      int a=37;
      bitset<74> bits1;
      bitset<74> bits2;
      compress(frag1, bits1);
      compress(frag2, bits2);
      compare(bits1, bits2);
   }

   difference = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   int minutes = difference/60;
   int seconds = difference - minutes * 60;

   if (seconds < 10){
      cout << "\nRunning time: " << minutes << ":0" << seconds << endl << endl;
   }else{
      cout << "\nRunning time: " << minutes << ":" << seconds << endl << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}

void compress(string& in, bitset<74>& out){
   char c;
   int b=0;
   for(int i=0; i<in.length(); ++i){
      c=in[i];
      b=2*i;
      switch(c){
        case 'A':
           break;
        case 'C':
           out.set(b+1);
           break;
        case 'G':
           out.set(b);
           break;
        case 'T':
           out.set(b);
           out.set(b+1);
           break;
        default:
           cout << "Invalid character in fragment.\n";
      }
   }
}

void compare(bitset<74>& a, bitset<74>& b){
   for(int i=0; i<74; ++i){
      if(a[i] != b[i]){
      }
   }
}
```

And the string harness...

```
// File: bittest.cc

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void compress(string&, bitset<74>&);
void compare(string&, string&);

int main()
{
   // Start timer
   std::clock_t start;
   double difference;
   start = std::clock();

   for(int i=0; i<10000000; ++i){
      string frag1="ATCGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGA";
      string frag2="AACGAACGAACGAACGAACGAACGAACGAACGAACGA";
      int a=37;
      bitset<74> bits1;
      bitset<74> bits2;
      compress(frag1, bits1);
      compress(frag2, bits2);
      compare(frag1, frag2);
   }

   difference = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   int minutes = difference/60;
   int seconds = difference - minutes * 60;

   if (seconds < 10){
      cout << "\nRunning time: " << minutes << ":0" << seconds << endl << endl;
   }else{
      cout << "\nRunning time: " << minutes << ":" << seconds << endl << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}

void compress(string& in, bitset<74>& out){
   char c;
   int b=0;
   for(int i=0; i<in.length(); ++i){
      c=in[i];
      b=2*i;
      switch(c){
        case 'A':
           break;
        case 'C':
           out.set(b+1);
           break;
        case 'G':
           out.set(b);
           break;
        case 'T':
           out.set(b);
           out.set(b+1);
           break;
        default:
           cout << "Invalid character in frag.\n";
      }
   }
}

void compare(string& a, string& b){
   for(int i=0; i<37; ++i){
      if(a[i] != b[i]){
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` shouldnt even exist

Comment: What compiler options are you using? I would expect an optimizing compiler to completely remove both `compare()` functions since they have no actual effect.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: g++. I made the compare() functions do something and the times are the same, so I guess g++ didn't remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the two comparison routines:

```
void compare(bitset<74>& a, bitset<74>& b){
   for(int i=0; i<74; ++i){
      if(a[i] != b[i]){
      }
   }
}
```

and

```
void compare(string& a, string& b){
   for(int i=0; i<37; ++i){
      if(a[i] != b[i]){
      }
   }
}
```

Right off the bat you can see that one is executing the loop `74` times and the other is executing the loop `37` times. So already the bitset approach is starting from a position of weakness.

Now consider the types of data being accessed; accessing individual bytes is reasonably quick; accessing individual bits from any data structure might store a single bit in an entire byte or maybe even some larger word size. If it stores bits in individual bits, then some bitmasking operations must be introduced, and those all take processing power too. If the bits are stored in bytes, then you are in fact comparing only *half* of each character on each bit. If the bits are stored in words or larger, you are increasing the size of the CPU's data cache -- potentially taking something that might fit entirely in one cache line to several cache lines. That's a potential for *gigantic* speed penalties, though on inputs this small, it's probably not too horrible yet.

If you replace your `bitset` with a `char[]` that is large enough to hold all your data, manually set the bits yourself in the compression routines, *and then compare the `char[]` array a byte at a time or larger*, you can probably drastically improve the speed of the comparison routines. Will the speed up be sufficient to overcome the cost of the compression routines? That's tough to say and depends in part upon how many comparisons you can make with each compressed form.

If you can perform your comparison using `int` or larger datatypes, you can probably go even significantly faster, as modern CPUs are usually faster at accessing 4-bytes or 8-bytes at a time than 1-byte at a time. Most `strcmp(3)` or `memcmp(3)` routines are optimized to perform *huge, aligned* reads. If you use `memcmp(3)` to do your comparison, you'll have the best chance of going at top speed -- and that goes for both the compressed and uncompressed versions.

Answer (score 2):

The CPU will not load anything smaller than a byte, which is eight bits.  Therefore, when your program treats a pair of bits, the CPU actually loads eight bits, then masks the unused six out.  The masking operation takes processor time.

You must trade memory-usage efficiency against execution time.  Which you prefer is your choice.

Comment: Or improve the comparison. Bit sequences can (mostly) be compared without unpacking them.

Comment: @duskwuff's suggestion is good.  If you follow it, pack 32 or 64 bits at a time, depending on whether you've a 32- or 64-bit processor.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. How can I implement a comparison that doesn't unpack the bit sequences (I have a 64-bit processor)?

Comment: @vincent: Why not AND two 32-bit numbers together, then count the bits and divide by two? This gives you the number of matches. You can do this in a few statements and it allows you to do 16 comparisons at once.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement the comparison most efficiently.  I would have to try various strategies and time them, but @sarnold's answer seems a good one from which to start.  Good luck.

Comment: @MikeBantegui: This sounds like exactly what I'm trying to do.  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @vincent:  Are you familiar with the bitwise operators?  These are << >> & | ^ ~.  You usually see << and >> with ostreams and istreams, but here I mean their completely different, low-level, bitwise use, as in ((1 << 5) == 32).  Also, are you handy with hexadecimal notation, as in (0x20 == 32)?  If not, these are what you would wish to learn to implement the bit-packing suggestions.

Comment: @vincent: See this link for more information: http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/